# Horizontally Centering Flexbox with Image and Text

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I have a div like this, where I want the text and image to be horizontally aligned, where the space from the left of the div and right of the div are equal. Here's the current code I have, though it is definitely not optimal:

```css
.window{
  position:absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color:#424242;
}
.content{
  padding-top:50px;
  width: 50%;
  position:relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:flex;
}
img {
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  min-width: 32px;
  min-height: 32px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.textcontent{
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: 16px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 182%;
}
.text{
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>


<div class="window">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/family-and-home-collection/110/Icon__grandfather-32.png" />
    <div class="textcontent">
      <div class="text"> Some Centered Text. </div>
      <div class="text"> Some Other Text. </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The issue is that the "window" could be any size, the image could be a fair amount of sizes, and the items in text content could be longer and larger font-size. Additionally, the second line of text is not always visible.

This is a problem, since if the text is very long, the 50% width is very small, and the text wraps several times when there is plenty of room.

```css
.window{
  position:absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color:#424242;
}
.content{
  padding-top:50px;
  width: 50%;
  position:relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:flex;
}
img {
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  min-width: 32px;
  min-height: 32px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.texcontentt{
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: 16px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 182%;
}
.text{
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>


<div class="window">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/family-and-home-collection/110/Icon__grandfather-32.png" />
    <div class="textcontent">
      <div class="text"> Some text that is very very long and wraps. </div>
      <div class="text"> This text is also very long and also wraps. </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I could counter this by making the width % in the .content rule larger, but then for small content in a large window, it will not be centered anymore.

Long story short, is there a better way to get the text centering I want for different sizes, without having to have it be very narrow?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To align your text and image horizontally inside div, you could use `display:flex` and `justify-content: center`. `Justify-content:center` will align the children at the center of the container.

```css
.content {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; /* Only if you want it vertically center-aligned as well */
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="window">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/family-and-home-collection/110/Icon__grandfather-32.png" />
    <div class="textcontent">
      <div class="text"> Some text that is very very long and wraps. </div>
      <div class="text"> This text is also very long and also wraps. </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View in CodePen](https://codepen.io/cooldhavs/pen/vRwOJx)

Hope this helps!

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What what the problem and what did you do to solve it?

Comment: Thank you! The main thing from this was justify-content: center instead of the width: 50%.